# How do one extract information from a dynamic table, automatically through excel functions?

Tags: excel, dynamic, filtering

I have been searching high and low for a way to solve my dilemma, in different ways, so I am trying to post both of the things I've been trying to do:

**The challenge version 1:**

- I want to extract the entire row with information tied to the name which is the latest entry of that name in the table. So from the table below I would want to collect the entire row which contains the information: "*A, Jack Black, 01.01.2029, 10:20*". I simply want to copy the entire row to another sheet. But one important factor is that it has to happen automatically.
- So i need functions which can check if: Is there another entry with the same name, higher up in the table? If so, DO NOT COPY THE ROW. If there ain't another entry with the exact same name higher up in the table, COPY THE ENTIRE ROW, to another table, within another sheet.

**The challenge version 2:**

- What I really want to do is count the number of unique people(unique names) per. department, and summarize this in another table. Basically this means that "Jack Black" should be counted as 1 person, in department A.

[image: TABLE X]

So the result I want, is a table looking like this (the one beneath), where the number of people does not contain any duplicate people (names). OR it does not function with a dynamic table, which updates the information it contains on the fly. I can make this happen if I am copying from a static table, but as stated above, the table is dynamic and updates with new information every minute...

[image: TABLE Y]

So far i've tried excel's built in filtering, but this does not work automatically. I've also tried using  functions like in this guide: https://excel-bytes.com/how-to-extract-a-dynamic-list-from-a-data-range-based-on-a-criteria-without-filters-in-excel/. However every solution i find seems to need criteria for filtering out duplicates or does not function when copying information from a dynamic table.

Does anyone know how to reach my desired result, without implementing criteria for selecting the rows or counting rows as stated above? VBA code is not an option at the moment :(

In advance, THANK YOU, I've really tried solving this, but I feel like this just might break my head wide open soon if I can't solve it. HEEEEELP!

Sincerely
haakonlu

Comment: Excel O365 has `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions which can help you.

Comment: Thanks man, i have not tried UNIQUE, i will check it out!